# Корректное отображение содержимого WPF при масштабировании Windows (100% - 175%)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

При разработке WPF приложения столкнулись со следующей проблемой.

Обнаружили, что если скомпилировать приложение при установленном пользователем масштабе операционной системе Windows(100%), содержимое WPF отображается корректно. Но стоит во время работы программы поменять масштабирование системы на любое другое(125-200%), содержимое WPF окна начинается размываться. Но если при выбранном масштабе заново собрать приложение, размытие пропадает.

Как с этим бороться ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не использовать растровые картинки?

Comment: @VladD растровые после пересборки не пофиксились бы наверное

Comment: @tym32167: Хотелось бы, конечно [mcve]

Comment: @tym32167: Может, они по-разному пакуются ка ресурсы при другом разрешении? В порядке бреда.

Comment: @Stiven: А какая версия Студии?

Comment: @VlaD: Версия VS 2017 15.8.2